# AngularJS, get element by dynamic id?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to build an unordered list. I am doing it like so:

```
<li id="listItem{{$index}}" ng-repeat="slide in data" ng-click="setActive(slide.slideIndex,$event)">
    <span class="listItemText">
    <b>{{slide.slideIndex + 1}}. </b>{{slide.Title}}
  </span>
</li>
```

I am giving each `<li>` a dynamic ID of `listItem0, listItem1, listItem2,....` etc. **I need to get that element in my controller**. I've been trying to use `angular.element()` but I can't get it work for the life of me.

The reason I need that element is because at certain events, I need my animation library (TweenLite) to auto scroll to that position. You are allowed to pass an element to TweenLite like so:

```
$scope.setActive = function(id, event)
{
    $scope.currentIndex = id;
    if (event) player.currentTime = $scope.data[id].time;
    if ($scope.autoScroll)
    {
        var target = document.getElementById("listItem" + id);
        TweenLite.to(slideList,0.5,{scrollTo:{y:target}});
    }
}
```

The problem is `target` always returns `null`. If I put target inside an `angular.element()` I get a giant object and no reference to the actual `<li>` (that I was able to find).

What am I doing wrong here and/or should I come at this differently? Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
player.addEventListener("timeupdate", function()
{
    currentTime = player.currentTime;
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key)
    {
        if (currentTime >= $scope.data[key].time && currentTime <= $scope.data[key].time + 0.3 && $scope.currentIndex != key)
        {
            $scope.$apply(function()
            {
                $scope.setActive(key);
            });     
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you are passing already contains a reference to the element. Try this:

```
TweenLite.to(slideList,0.5,{scrollTo:{y:event.target}});
```

Comment: I didn't know event carried target with it. Good to know. The issue I have right now is I have a video player with cue points (I added that function to my original question). I call `setActive()` when a cue point is hit. In that case, there is no click event through `ng-click` hence why I originally tested for `if (event)...`

Comment: Are you sure slide.slideIndex and $index match? Try setting id="listItem{{slide.slideIndex}}"

Comment: `$index` starts at 0 and `slide.slideIndex` starts at 0. The reason I have a slideIndex is when I filter the list items, I want the correct numbers next to the list items like `1,5,8,12` etc. If I was to use `$index` they would show `1,2,3,4` etc when filtering

Comment: Then you still need to set id="listItem{{slide.slideIndex}}"

Comment: oh yeah that is true! but this still wont solve my issue of event always having a value

Comment: If there is a method for just obtaining an element through the controller, I think I'd be set. I haven't been able to successfully do this yet

Comment: No need to always have an event - follow what you already have but ensure the index you are passing and the ids you are generating match. So pick slideIndex for example and be consistent - dump $index. Do the same in timeupdate - instead of passing key (which won't match ater filtering), pass value.slideIndex

Comment: Your problem in not getting the element. document.getElementById should be just fine. Your problem is most likely mismatched indexes.

Comment: I have no problem getting the ID of the row. Running `console.log(document.getElementById("listItem" + id));` gives me `null` when `listItem0` is definitely there

Comment: Trust me, if there was an element with id="listItem0", document.getElementById would have found it. Check in web inspector. In your case "id" is not 0.

Comment: Here is a screen shot from chrome dev tools. It is clearly there. http://ronnieswietek.com/_random/listitem.jpg also, `console.log(document.getElementById("listItem" + id));` equates to `listItem0`